# How to get a registry value and set into a variable in batch

Tags: batch, windows-registry

I need to get a value in a registry key and store in a variable using a batch file.

I wrote a basic command line to exemplify my logic (using echo instead of setting a variable):

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=    " %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v "LastUsedUsername" ^|findstr /ri "REG_SZ"') do echo=%%a
```

I expect the username to be printed in the screen, but it doesn't happen.

I am sure the Registry value "LastUsedUsername" is not empty, it really has data.
Also, the delimiter is a tab, not spaces.

**EDIT**

If I just type

```
reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v "LastUsedUsername"
```

... it returns:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
    LastUsedUsername    REG_SZ    Administrador
```

This code

```
reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v "LastUsedUsername" ^| findstr /ri "REG_SZ"
```

... returns:

```
    LastUsedUsername    REG_SZ    Administrador
```

Then, when I use the for command, I just get no output from echo.

Comment: What makes you sure the delimiter is tab? On my Win8.1 it's several spaces (looks like 4).

Comment: I typed "tab" in notepad. When I copy from notepad to here, the tab turns into these 4 spaces.

Comment: John: I mean on 8.1 when I do the `reg query` the output uses spaces not tab, as @DaveO v2 agrees. Parsing with delims=(tab) doesn't work, parsing with the default does.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. You and he are correct. I have an very old .bat script that uses tab as delimiter and it still works even on my Windows 8. Thinking about why it works and my script doesn't, I guess it's because the reg.exe (used in the old script) is an older version than Windows 8 native reg.exe. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need the delims switch, at all, since the default is space, which is what the reg query is returning. In making a bat file for this for loop and registry on a key that I am messing with I get the correct echo, for my instance the "Red" value of the RGB Background color is 55:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\Colors"  /V Background  ^|findstr /ri "REG_SZ"') do echo %%a
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. I thought the reg query output was a tab.

Comment: Note that this will not work as expected if there are white-space characters in the value. See https://superuser.com/a/1488030/1640438

Answer (score 15):

The approved answer is not correct in some situations - if value read from the registry containst white characters i.e. spaces (Program Files (x86)) then it returns only the first part of the value ('Program').
What is I worked out is:

```
FOR /F "tokens=2* skip=2" %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion" /v "CommonFilesDir"') do echo %%b
```

The result is `C:\Program Files\Common Files`

Comment: Good catch. But when querying the path variable, it prints it twice for some reason. The workaround I found was to use `@echo`
`FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=2*" %a in ('reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v path') do @echo %b`. `set` doesn't have the same issue though.

Comment: This answer is broken, not only it says `%%a` in one spot and then `%%b` in another, but it also returns `REG_SZ` instead of value.

Comment: @IgorLevicki The answer isn't broken, but you did successfully manage to break it. If you had just left it with `%%b` at the end, you would have gotten the correct response. When executing a `for /f` loop with the `tokens` option set to retrieve multiple values (like `tokens=2,*` meaning get the second part and then everything that comes after — the comma may be omitted as in the answer), `cmd.exe` populates the specified variable with a one-character name and the required number of extra variables with consecutive characters as names for the extra values requested (here, the single `%%b`).

Comment: @Taederias I stand corrected, I am using batch scripts a lot and I didn't know about that. I think that it would be worth explaining / mentioning that in the answer itself.

Comment: @IgorLevicki Yeah, the shell just wantonly assigning variables does appear awkward and weird, especially from the perspective of someone used to “proper” programming languages. Here it appears as a sort of workaround for batch files having no concept of arrays, or really any complex data structures. (Side note though: when one thinks a piece of code is incorrect, it is generally prudent to at least try out said code _as provided_ before making such claims.)

Comment: @Taederias I did try the code, but I "auto-corrected" it because I assumed `%%b` was a typo since I wasn't familiar with the concept, and it was not explained in your answer. So once again I apologize for saying your answer is wrong, but I still think that editing the answer to add an explanation would be beneficial for others because as it is you are just teaching people to copy-paste without understanding how it works and why.

Comment: @IgorLevicki Um, correction: this is not *my* answer, I just saw your comment and decided to come and clear things up. I fundamentally agree with your statement that this would be worth mentioning, and I could propose and edit, though I do not have the reputation required to just flat-out apply it myself. P.S. I didn't mean to demand an apology or such, I was just trying to be helpful and give advice on avoiding this kind of situation in the future. Sorry if it came out that way.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of the DOS command is correct. I would question whether you have the correct registry key value. Just type the req query... part into the command line and see what is returns. I am running Win 7 and I do not find the key , LastUsedUsername, defined in HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon

Comment: I edited the question to add more info and answer you better. According to the output, the registry key value is correct. Anyway, I changed the value "LastUsedUsername" to "Shell". I should get "explorer.exe" as output, but I didn't. So, I believe something is wrong in FOR command

Answer (score -1):

setx can do what you want, no need for a script:

```
setx DefaultUserName /k "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\DefaultUserName"
```

Note: The variable can't be used in the current command script as it is set in the user's environment, not in the current environment. Check with

```
echo %DefaultUserName% (doesn't work OOTB but will work in a new cmd window)
reg query "HKCU\Volatile Environment" /v "DefaultUserName" (doesn't work)
reg query "HKCU\Environment" /v "DefaultUserName" (works)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not only it won't work in current batch file, but it also cannot be told which registry to read (32-bit or 64-bit). Useless.